# No space left on disk indication but there is space free

Tags: kernel, compiling, disk-usage

During compilation of the 4.10.1 kernel the following occurs:

```
limnaios@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-4.10.1$ sudo make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.10.1 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.1 /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.1
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.1 /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.1
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.1
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.1 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:191: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:254: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
limnaios@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-4.10.1$
```

However, when I use the df -h command I get:

```
limnaios@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-4.10.1$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        767M  8.9M  758M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   34G  168G  17% /
tmpfs                        3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    236M   75M  150M  34% /boot
cgmfs                        100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                        767M     0  767M   0% /run/user/1002
limnaios@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-4.10.1$
```

So, why do I get the message that /boot has no space, even though it's up to 34%?

Update:

df -i returns

```
Filesystem                    Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                          976431    545   975886    1% /dev
tmpfs                         981097    710   980387    1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 14139392 280316 13859076    2% /
tmpfs                         981097      2   981095    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         981097      4   981093    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         981097     17   981080    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      62248    308    61940    1% /boot
cgmfs                         981097     13   981084    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                         981097      4   981093    1% /run/user/1002
```

while ls -alh /boot/ returns

```
total 66M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 1.0K Mar  2 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Jan  3 12:09 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 199K Mar  2 09:48 config-4.10.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 199K Mar  2 09:41 config-4.10.1.old
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 196K Mar  1 11:13 config-4.9.13-typoramadspace
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1.0K Mar  1 17:06 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  33M Mar  1 14:20 initrd.img-4.9.13-typoramadspace
drwx------  2 root root  12K Jun  9  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.5M Mar  2 09:48 System.map-4.10.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.5M Mar  2 09:41 System.map-4.10.1.old
-rw-------  1 root root 3.9M Mar  1 13:55 System.map-4.9.13-typoramadspace
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6.8M Mar  2 09:48 vmlinuz-4.10.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6.8M Mar  2 09:41 vmlinuz-4.10.1.old
-rw-------  1 root root 6.8M Mar  1 13:55 vmlinuz-4.9.13-typoramadspace
```

and dpkg -l | grep linux-image returns

```
ii  linux-image-4.9.13-typoramadspace     1                                   amd64        Linux kernel binary image for version 4.9.13-typoramadspace
```

Comment: And `df -i`  also `ls -alh /boot/` please

Comment: Add to the post `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` and `ls -lah /boot` please. Your initrd may be too large, or your kernel is statically linked instead of using module in `/lib/modules`
? My 4.9.0 stock Stretch install uses up 34MB in /boot, but then it is a VM without firmware blobs in initrd. As things it is, your /boot is clearly small to have more one version of the kernel+initrd there. If you only have one version installed, and it is already using around 65MB (75MB - grub), it is easy to understand a new, bigger version wont fit in a 150MB partition. Is the previous version compiled too?

Comment: It would be worth monitoring the disk space as you build the initramfs. `watch -n1 df -h /boot` in a different window (or `clear; while :; do tput home; date; echo; df -h /boot; sleep 1; done` if you don't have `watch` installed.). You will probably see the available disk space shrink to zero... at which point you need to consider either enlarging `/boot` (typically tricky) or carving a bigger partition out of the disk from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the 5% 'root' reserve on /boot. you can remove it with the tune2fs command: 
`sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1`

By default there is a 5% reserve of disk space for root user. so 5% of 150mb would be 7.5mb you can salvage for free!

also try `apt-get autoremove` to purge out old kernels. you can find more at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

hopefully that helps you get enough free space.